# Google App Engine Cron jobs sporadically not running for extended periods

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I have only just noticed an irregularity in activation of my cron tasks (heretofore, thought to be running normally on our fancy system).

I have scheduled cron to hit a URL (/Alerter) every 1 minutes - it runs fine. Then unexpectedly, the URL ceases to be called by cron for a period of ~20 mins - this can occur about once every 2 hours, but often more regularly (for instance, 2016-1-25 09:49-10:08 GMT, and on 2 occasions in the previous 2 hours..)
I cannot spot a pattern in this behavior and further Jetty investigation is not possible. Project & cron detail below. Can any one with more rights than I explain this?
   Thank you!
   -Paul

```
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/Alerter</url>
        <description>check for alerts to send</description>
            <schedule>every 1 minutes</schedule>
    </cron>  
</cronentries>
```

My Project ID is (#815536548670)

Comment: What does the cron job status page say (Project dashboard >> App Engine >> Task Queues >> Cron Jobs). You should see a list of your jobs and their last run time. Also, is there anything interesting in the logs for the relevant hours?

Comment: I've been monitoring this all day as suggested, what I see is this:

Comment: I've been monitoring this all day as suggested, what I see is this:     When the Cron is running normally the Task Query/ Cron Job console shows the relevant data, last run =  'success' etc.   When the Cron is not running, Clicking into Task Query immediately displays "The server has encountered a problem. Please try again"... Leading me to suspect that something outside my scope is malfunctioning.

Comment: Have you looked at the App Engine logs to see what went wrong in the task? (You should look for the task handler `/Alerter` path)

Comment: Yep, that's how i know my Task isn't being triggered. There is no call at all to "/Alerter" in the logs during these outages. Usually it appears every minute. All other services and URL calls in my application are working just fine when the Cron-invoked calls are not happening..

Comment: What about quota limits?

Comment: Making a couple of assumptions here, but: If your scaling was set to "manual" your cron task could be the culprit. May I suggest that you move the logic out of the cron task and into a task queue task. Then in the cron task only schedule the task queue task. I'm not sure that cron will allow parallel execution of the same task, the way task queues do. So that would be an interesting test.

Comment: Hi - nope its not Quota-related either. I eventually got into The task queue console while this outage was occurring (cron only stops for ~20 mins and then starts ticking again all by itself), The console shows a successful last run - albeit 5 mins ago, rather than 1 minute ago. When I manually run the cron task, the console displays : "Success", last run "2016-01-26 (12:59:12)
4 min 11 sec late" - so even it knows its late....